# Check constraint on partitioned tables in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, indexing, database-partitioning, sql-view, indexed-view

In our MSSQL server 2008 R2 environment, we have a table which we have partitioned based on a yearly partition function.

We need to define a view on this table and want to take advantage of table partitioning while running query on this query.

From following text quoted from MSDN I understand that we will need to create a CHECK constraint on our partitioned tables.

> CHECK constraints are not needed for the partitioned view to return
>   the correct results. However, if the CHECK constraints have not been
>   defined, the query optimizer must search all the tables instead of
>   only those that cover the search condition on the partitioning column.

Please suggest how I can achieve this. If, in case, I am wrong in my approach, please help me correct the same.

Comment: partitioned tables and partitioned views are different things. If you already have a partitioned table, you don't need to define a partitioned view on it, and so the text you're quoting is irrelevant.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever We need a view which is a sub-table from our partitioned table with some manipulation. While querying on this view we want to take advantage of partitioning on our main table.  Please suggest how I can achieve this.

Comment: Write the view. Done. Like I said, the text you're quoting relates to partitioned views, which are a different thing, and not something that you need.

Comment: But if we write a simple view then its running query across all the partitions of table. Please suggest what we can do to let  query in view take advantage of partition on table.

Comment: thanks for your response, I was able to make it work by tweaking our query. We need to include our partition column in our query in view to take benefit of table partition.